# can not parsing json data to datatable

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I have code like that

```
 $.ajax({ 
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'classfication_of_productjson.html',
                dataType : 'json',
                data : {
                    "search_bunrui_code" : code,
                    "orderType" : orderType,
                    "search_base_date_from" : search_base_date_from,
                    "search_base_date_to" : search_base_date_to,
                    "compare_date_from" : compare_date_from,
                    "compare_date_to" : compare_date_to,
                    "compare_menu" : compare_menu,
                    "shopCode0000" : shopCode0000,
                    "shopCode0001" : shopCode0001,
                    "shopCode0002" : shopCode0002,
                    "shopCode0009" : shopCode0009,
                    "shopCode0003" : shopCode0003,
                    "shopCode0006" : shopCode0006,
                    "shopCode9000" : shopCode9000,
                    "shopCode9001" : shopCode9001
                },


                success : function(data) {
                        $('#dataTable').dataTable({
                        "bProcessing": true,
                        "bServerSide": true,
                        "aaSorting": [[1,'desc']],
                        "aaData": $.parseJSON(data),
                        "iDisplayLength": 10,
                        "bDeferRender": true,
                        "bJQueryUI": true,
                        "sPaginationType": "two_button",
                        "bRetrieve":[],
                        "bDestroy": [],
                        "aoColumns": [
                            {"mData": "brand_code"},
                            {"mData": "brand_name"},
                            {"mData": "bunrui_code"},
                            {"mData": "compare_jyutyuu_hanbai"},
                            {"mData": "compare_jyutyuu_profit"},
                            {"mData": "compare_jyutyuu_profit_rate"},
                            {"mData": "compare_jyutyuu_sikiri"},
                            {"mData": "compare_jyutyuu_teika"},
                            {"mData": "compare_nouhin_hanbai"},
                            {"mData": "compare_nouhin_profit"},
                            {"mData": "compare_nouhin_profit_rate"},
                            {"mData": "compare_nouhin_sikiri"},
                            {"mData": "compare_nouhin_teika"},
                            {"mData": "compare_syouhin_count"},
                            {"mData": "dummy_column"},
                            {"mData": "jyutyuu_hanbai"},
                            {"mData": "jyutyuu_profit"},
                            {"mData": "jyutyuu_profit_rate"},
                            {"mData": "jyutyuu_sikiri"},
                            {"mData": "jyutyuu_teika"},
                            {"mData": "list_no"},
                            {"mData": "nouhin_hanbai"},
                            {"mData": "nouhin_profit"},
                            {"mData": "nouhin_profit_rate"},
                            {"mData": "nouhin_sikiri"},
                            {"mData": "nouhin_teika"},
                            {"mData": "rate_jyutyuu_hanbai"},
                            {"mData": "rate_jyutyuu_profit"},
                            {"mData": "rate_jyutyuu_profit_rate"},
                            {"mData": "rate_jyutyuu_sikiri"},
                            {"mData": "rate_jyutyuu_teika"},
                            {"mData": "rate_nouhin_hanbai"},
                            {"mData": "rate_nouhin_profit"},
                            {"mData": "rate_nouhin_profit_rate"},
                            {"mData": "rate_nouhin_sikiri"},
                            {"mData": "rate_nouhin_teika"},
                            {"mData": "rate_syouhin_count"},
                            {"mData": "siire_code"},
                            {"mData": "siire_name"},
                            {"mData": "siire_rate"},
                            {"mData": "syouhin_code"}
                        ]

                    });
```

And I have the return json data from the server like that

```
{
    "aaData": [
        {
            "brand_code": "1586",
            "brand_name": "74Daijiro:74ダイジロー",
            "bunrui_code": "0001",
            "bunrui_name": "バイク本体",
            "compare_jyutyuu_hanbai": 0,
            "compare_jyutyuu_profit": 0,
            "compare_jyutyuu_profit_rate": 0,
            "compare_jyutyuu_sikiri": 0,
            "compare_jyutyuu_teika": 0,
            "compare_nouhin_hanbai": 0,
            "compare_nouhin_profit": 0,
            "compare_nouhin_profit_rate": 0,
            "compare_nouhin_sikiri": 0,
            "compare_nouhin_teika": 0,
            "compare_syouhin_count": 0,
            "dummy_column": "",
            "jyutyuu_hanbai": 227000,
            "jyutyuu_profit": 73091,
            "jyutyuu_profit_rate": 32.19,
            "jyutyuu_sikiri": 153909,
            "jyutyuu_teika": 227000,
            "list_no": 0,
            "nouhin_hanbai": 0,
            "nouhin_profit": 0,
            "nouhin_profit_rate": 0,
            "nouhin_sikiri": 0,
            "nouhin_teika": 0,
            "rate_jyutyuu_hanbai": 0,
            "rate_jyutyuu_profit": 0,
            "rate_jyutyuu_profit_rate": 0,
            "rate_jyutyuu_sikiri": 0,
            "rate_jyutyuu_teika": 0,
            "rate_nouhin_hanbai": 0,
            "rate_nouhin_profit": 0,
            "rate_nouhin_profit_rate": 0,
            "rate_nouhin_sikiri": 0,
            "rate_nouhin_teika": 0,
            "rate_syouhin_count": 0,
            "siire_code": null,
            "siire_name": null,
            "siire_rate": 85,
            "syouhin_code": "74d001",
            "syouhin_count": 1,
            "syouhin_spec": "",
            "syouhin_sys_code": "20521938",
            "syouhin_sys_name": "74Daijiro 車体"
        },
        {
            "brand_code": "1360",
            "brand_name": "TERRA MOTORS:テラモーターズ",
            "bunrui_code": "0001",
            "bunrui_name": "バイク本体",
            "compare_jyutyuu_hanbai": 0,
            "compare_jyutyuu_profit": 0,
            "compare_jyutyuu_profit_rate": 0,
            "compare_jyutyuu_sikiri": 0,
            "compare_jyutyuu_teika": 0,
            "compare_nouhin_hanbai": 0,
            "compare_nouhin_profit": 0,
            "compare_nouhin_profit_rate": 0,
            "compare_nouhin_sikiri": 0,
            "compare_nouhin_teika": 0,
            "compare_syouhin_count": 0,
            "dummy_column": "",
            "jyutyuu_hanbai": 38000,
            "jyutyuu_profit": 12137,
            "jyutyuu_profit_rate": 31.93,
            "jyutyuu_sikiri": 25863,
            "jyutyuu_teika": 38000,
            "list_no": 0,
            "nouhin_hanbai": 38000,
            "nouhin_profit": 12137,
            "nouhin_profit_rate": 31.93,
            "nouhin_sikiri": 25863,
            "nouhin_teika": 38000,
            "rate_jyutyuu_hanbai": 0,
            "rate_jyutyuu_profit": 0,
            "rate_jyutyuu_profit_rate": 0,
            "rate_jyutyuu_sikiri": 0,
            "rate_jyutyuu_teika": 0,
            "rate_nouhin_hanbai": 0,
            "rate_nouhin_profit": 0,
            "rate_nouhin_profit_rate": 0,
            "rate_nouhin_sikiri": 0,
            "rate_nouhin_teika": 0,
            "rate_syouhin_count": 0,
            "siire_code": null,
            "siire_name": null,
            "siire_rate": 76,
            "syouhin_code": "w-charge-004",
            "syouhin_count": 1,
            "syouhin_spec": "",
            "syouhin_sys_code": "19872078",
            "syouhin_sys_name": "アクシア 専用充電器"
        }
    ],
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 2,
    "iTotalRecords": 2,
    "sEcho": 1
}
```

But the datatable always show empty. Anyone has experience in datatable please give a an advise please!
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Without provided more error information (such as console errors) or an example of it live, there's not much we can do. But at a quick guess, your `aaData` key uses the parsed JSON which also contains some non-data fluff (i.e. `sEcho`). Assumingly that parameter only wants to receieve the `aaData` of your source.

So try changing:

`"aaData": $.parseJSON(data),`

to

`"aaData": $.parseJSON(data).aaData,`

<sub>**Note: it would probably be best practice to parse the jSON outside of the datatable initialiser and check the aaData key exists before trying to use it. But the above code should work to tell you if the error is what i think it is**</sub>

Comment: Sorry that i don't know how to provide an example of it live. And actually the console shows no erro. I do as your suggestion that change to "aaData": $.parseJSON(data) but the console shows error that Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aaData' of null

Comment: Therefore the parsing of the JSON is null, and is not an object, so that is your problem. I've just realised your ajax is set to json type, so it will be parsed prior to you getting the response data. To that end, try changing it to `"aaData": data.aaData`

Comment: When I change it to "aaData": data.aaData, it turns back to the first time that the datatable show empty

Comment: Your going to have to use console.log() and log the data/data.aaData and find where your data is. My suscpicion is that there is no data and the value your passing into the datatable is `null`. Without a live working link to your table, it's not really that easy to debug it. So you're going to have to work it out yourself. Console.log() the data until you get an array of data objects, thats what you need to pass into datatables